# Integers with odd number of prime factors

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Let d(n) be the number of integers less then n which has an odd number of prime factors ( 2,3,5,7,8,11,12,13,17,18...).

How to prove d(n)/n have a limit 1/2?

Is there for all m an n such that $|n-2d(n)|>m$?

Comment: For the second question, quite a bit more is known. There is a positive constant $k$ such that $|n-2d(n)|>k\sqrt{n}$ for infinitely many $n$.

Comment: what is the largest such k?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can begin to chase down things by starting at [this link.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_function)

In particular, for the second question, quite a bit more is known. There is a positive constant $k$ such that $|n-2d(n)|>k\sqrt{n}$ for infinitely many $n$.